# ECONNRESET error when performing a GET request

Tags: api, rest, request

I'm trying to make a GET request to a REST Aviation Weather API called [AVWX](https://avwx.rest/) but after performing the request it holds for about 10 seconds and then I get the following error displayed in the console:

```js
throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: read ECONNRESET
    at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:211:20)
Emitted 'error' event on ClientRequest instance at:
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:447:9)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:394:28)
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:157:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:122:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
  errno: -4077,
  code: 'ECONNRESET',
  syscall: 'read'
```

Here's my `HTTPS.request` function call:

```js
HTTPS.request({
    hostname: 'avwx.rest',
    port: 443,
    path: '/api/metar/KJFK',
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'myToken',
    },
}, res => {
    console.log(`statusCode: ${res.statusCode}`);

    res.on('data', d => {
        process.stdout.write(d);
    });
});
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Did you forget to call `req.end()` ?

Comment: Ugh, yes that was it. Thank you very much @Evert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Ever said in a comment on the question, I was missing `req.end()`.